# Installing Atom.io -- on a machine with Intel processor and 32bit Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, atom-editor

I am very much interested in installing [Atom.io](https://atom.io)!

My machine:

- 32bit Ubuntu
- Intel processor

However, the only download i can find for Atom.io is

- atom-amd64.deb

My question is two parts:

- Will i be able to dpkg -i this?
- If successful, will I run into problems later?

I know that I could build from source, and I will if need be.

Thanks

Comment: My answer here is just about how to install Atom text editor 32-bit in Ubuntu, but I have also answered some of your other questions about installing Atom text editor in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/468359/installing-atom-text-editor-on-32-bit-ubuntu/558751#558751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom text editor is currently available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu from the Atom text editor PPA with different builds for 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. Atom text editor can be installed from the terminal by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt update
sudo apt install atom
```

The current version of Atom text editor from ppa:webupd8team/atom is <s>1.1.0</s> 1.26.1.

There is currently (as of the date of this revision) an Atom text editor snap package that can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu using the command `sudo snap install --classic atom` however the Atom snap package is only available for 64-bit OSs.